# Inapp purchases and Subscriptions (Sell Once) android

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

**I am providing levels in app (easy(unlocked),fun,crazy,hard)**
want the users to buy only once and when they return they should have subscription.
I achieved it by saving in room database
But if I don't consume purchase it gets refunded. If I consume purchase when user comes back he has to buy again (the restore does not works)

What could be the solution?
If we use Subscriptions they are for specific period of time and user has to pay again for renewal but I want them permanent stick with that user.

Answer (score 0):

For non-consumed purchases you need to [acknowledge](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#process) them or they will be automatically refunded in a couple days.

From the docs:

> Note: If you do not acknowledge a purchase within three days, the user automatically receives a refund, and Google Play revokes the purchase.